# Does Huggingface's T5 Model Vocabulary include English-only version?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

Does anyone know if HuggingFace's T5 model (small) comes with mono-language vocabulary? The T5 paper by Google indicates that their vocabulary is trained on English and 3 other languages. Is there a version of this vocabulary that contains English only vocabulary?

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the publicly available [model card definition](https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/t5-small-config.json), the HuggingFace T5-small also seems to contain the necessary translation tasks, which makes it a multi-lingual model. Note that the summarization task should still be English-only, so depending on your task, this might not matter too much.